# Disable TLS certificate check for WebTestClient

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I am using Spring WebFlux WebTestClient in integration tests. I create client using `WebTestClient.bindToServer()`. Tested server serves resources with HTTPS. I have following code:

```
WebTestClient webTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToServer()
    .baseUrl("https://secured.example.com")
    .build();
webTestClient.get().uri("/index.html")
    .exchange()
    .expectStatus().isOk();
```

There is no need to use *valid* certificate in tests. How can I configure WebTestClient to trust all certificates?

P.S. I can configure WebClient to trust everyone. But WebTestClient is more suitable for writing tests.

Comment: Can you show us your configuration, that might help in answering the question? Always include the code you have and any attempts to solve it to give us more context. Useful resource on how to ask good questions (and those get answered more quickly) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Actually, I am confused a little bit. I come here from https://spring.io/questions But it seems that such questions do not imply quick answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure that with a custom `ClientHttpConnector` that you can provide to the `WebTestClient`.

```
// create a custom connector and customize TLS configuration there.
ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(options -> options...);
WebTestClient client = WebTestClient.bindToServer(connector);
```

This has been fixed recently in [SPR-16168](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16168).

Comment: Brian, I was the one who created [SPR-16168](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16168). It worth to add that changes will be available in version 5.0.2 which are going to be released in a few days.